# Restart page numbering for memoir appendix

Tags: memoir, page-numbering, appendices

My thesis is too big (540 pages) for one volume impression, so I need to separate my appendices from the main thesis text.

But I want only one pdf file with the two main titles: one for the thesis and one for the appendix page, with the appendix page numbering restart to 0.

Is this possible with memoir class?

**Volume 1:**

- A page with Title of the thesis
- Toc
- Thesis content (chapter 1 .. n) page 0 .. 450
- Bibliography

**Volume 2:**

- A page with Title : "Appendices to the thesis ... "
- my Appendix A - p 0 ... 15
- my Appendix B - p 15 ... 30

  ```
  % !TEX encoding =  UTF-8 Unicode
  % -*- program: xelatex -*-
  \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,twoside, openright]{memoir}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \usepackage{mwe} % just for dummy images
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \newsubfloat{figure}
  \newsubfloat{table}

  \title{My Thesis title}
  \author{Sébastien R}
  \date{2015}

  \newcommand{\polimi}{Université Panthéon-Sorbonne\xspace}
  \newcommand{\dei}{Ecole Doctorale de Géographie de Paris\xspace}
  \newcommand{\POLIMI}{\uppercase{\polimi}}
  \newcommand{\DEI}{\uppercase{\dei}}

  % titles:
  \renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{%
    %\license %COMMENT THIS TO REMOVE THE DISCLAIMER NOTE
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-c}\\[.5cm]
    \POLIMI\\
    \emph{\dei}\\[.2cm]
   My thesis
    \par
    \hrulefill
    \vfill}
  \renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{\vfill}
  \renewcommand{\maketitlehookc}{%
    \vfill
    \begin{flushleft}
      \textbf{Directrice :}\\
      director \\[.3cm]
      \textbf{Co-directrice :}\\
      co director\\[.3cm]
     Membres du Jury:\\
       \begin{tabular}{ r l }
      \textbf{Rapporteur  :}& rapporteur 2 \\
      \textbf{Rapporteur  :}& rapporteur 1 \\
   \end{tabular}
    \end{flushleft}
    \vfill}
  \preauthor{\begin{flushright}Thèse de doctorat de:\\\bfseries}
  \postauthor{\end{flushright}}


  \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Annexes}
  \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Annexes}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{titlingpage}
    \maketitle
  \end{titlingpage}

  \frontmatter

  \cleardoublepage

  \chapterstyle{bringhurst}

  \tableofcontents

  \mainmatter
  \chapter{my first chapter}
  \lipsum    

  \chapter{my second chapter}
  \lipsum    

  \listoftables

  \listoffigures

  \appendix
  \appendixpage


  \chapter{my first appendix}
  \lipsum    

  \chapter{my second appendix}
  \lipsum    

  \end{document}
  ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general:

To reset arabic pagenumbering use `\pagenumbering{arabic}` which sets the next page number to 1.

To set the pagenumber to 0 use `\setcounter{page}{0}`

So for your case try:

```
end of volume 1
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{0}
start of volume 2
```

I think that starting your second volume with page number 0 will strike the reader as unusual, particularly if the document is printed two-sided and the even numbered pages appear on the right and the odd ones on the left.